# jQuery AJAX php Login Not passing data properly

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, mysqli

I get a Failure object Object notice. I have looked at multiple examples and still can't figure out the error. I believe my AJAX is not set up properly. The PHP should be good to go, I have a local database and use jQuery with AJAX to handle the request and the response. The page should redirect to the dashboard.php when I have success with logging in.

Here is the form:

```
<div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12 text-center">
                <h1 class="text_white bad_login">
                    Log In Please
                </h1>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-sm-offset-4">
                <form class="text_white" method="post" action="/login.php">
                    <div class="form-group">
                      <label for="username">User Name:</label>
                      <input name="username" type="text" class="form-control" id="username" placeholder="User Name">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                      <label for="password">Password:</label>
                      <input name="password" type="password" class="form-control" id="password" placeholder="Password">
                    </div>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" id="login" name="login">Log In</button>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Here is the PHP:

```
if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST")
{

        // grab form fields and save as php variables
        $username = '';
        $password = '';

//        if (isset($_POST['name'], $_POST['passphrase'])){
//            $username = $_POST['name'];
//            echo $username;
//            
//            $password = $_POST['pass'];
//            echo $password;
//        }
//        else {
//            $username = null;
//            $password = null;
//        }

        if (isset($_POST['password'])){
            $password = $_POST['password'];
            //echo $password;
        }
        else {
            $password = null;
        }

        if (isset($_POST['username'])){
            $username = $_POST['username'];
            //echo $username;
        }
        else {
            $username = null;
        }

        // create query to run on database
        $qry =  "SELECT username, password FROM user WHERE username='".$username. "' AND password='".$password. "' ";


        $result = mysqli_query($conn, $qry) or die(mysqli_error($conn));
        $num_row = mysqli_num_rows($result);
        $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);

        // check to see if it is only 1 match and then save that information to the session for later use
        if( $num_row == 1 ) {
            $_SESSION['username'] = $row['username'];
            //echo $_SESSION['username'];

            $_SESSION['password'] = $row['password'];
            //echo $_SESSION['password'];
        }
        else {
            echo ' FALSE! ';
        }

//        $result->json_encode($result);
        echo json_encode($result);
    }

//close the connection
$conn->close();
```

Here is the AJAX which i believe contains the error:

```
//jQuery(document).ready(function($){
//    $('#login').click(function(event){
//       event.preventDefault();
//       var username = $('#username').val(); 
//       var password = $('#password').val();
//       
//       if ( $('#username').val() === '' || $('#password').val() === '') {
//           $('.bad_login').text('PLEASE ENTER BOTH USERNAME AND PASSWORD');
//       }
//       
//       $.ajax({
//           type: 'POST',
//           url: '/ChurchCheckIn/login.php',
//           dataType: 'json',
//           data: 'username='+username+'&password='+password,
////           data: { username : username, password : password},
//           success: function(data){
////               if(data === 'true') {
//                   window.location='/ChurchCheckIn/dashboard.php';
//                   console.log('if true.... ' + data);
////               }
////               else {
////                   $('.bad_login').text('WRONG USERNAME OR PASSWORD TRY AGAIN PLEASE...');
////                   console.log('bad html test for other stuff' + data);
////               }
//           },
////                fail: function(data){
////                    jQuery.parseJSON(data);
////                    console.log('failure' + data);
////                    $('.bad_login').text('WRONG USERNAME OR PASSWORD TRY AGAIN PLEASE...');
////                },
////                done: function() {
////                    console.log('success' + data);
////                    window.location='/ChurchCheckIn/dashboard.php';
////                },
//           beforeSend:function() {
//               $('.bad_login').text('Loading....');
//           }
//       });
//       return false;
//    });
//});

jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    $('#login').click(function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var username = $('#username').val();
        var password = $('#password').val();
        var response = {};

        if ($('#username').val() === '' || $('#password').val() === '') {
            $('.bad_login').text('PLEASE ENTER BOTH USERNAME AND PASSWORD');
        }

        var request = $.ajax({
            url: '/ChurchCheckIn/login.php',
            type: 'POST',
            data: 'username='+username+'&password='+password,
            dataType: 'json'
        });

        request.done(function (data) {
            response = $.parseJSON(data);
            console.log(response);
            if (response.success == 'true') {
                console.log('success' + data);
                window.location = '/ChurchCheckIn/dashboard.php';
            } else {
                console.log('data came back false');
            }
        });

        request.fail(function (data) {
            console.log('failure' + data);
            $('.bad_login').text('WRONG USERNAME OR PASSWORD TRY AGAIN PLEASE...');
        });

    });

});
```

I have tried multiple ways, i believe one sends an object and the other expects to receive a string. I don't believe I am way offbase, I even made sure to use the newest practices. mysqli in my php and the newer form of success with my jQuery.

Comment: I see a problem with your javascript code. It's all commented out. Follow the advice in this article to isolate your problem. [mcve]

Comment: Need to isolate your problem more. Inspect actual request in browser dev tools network to see that what is sendt is what is expected and to see what is returned (if any)

Comment: echo's are all messed up. Can't echo text and json , nor send a query object

Comment: don't i need to echo what gets passed? does it need to be an object?

Answer (score 1):

Try using data as Javascript object

```
    var request = $.ajax({
        url: '/ChurchCheckIn/login.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: {username: username, password: password}
        dataType: 'json'
    });
```

if that didn't work, use [JSON.stringify](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) around the data object, but it should work because [jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) converts the data object automatically.

Answer (score 1):

I believe in a row:

```html
if (response.success == 'true') {
}
```

there is no element `success` try check if response variable is not empty.